# Why is the whole "Jiro Dreams of Sushi" documentary spoken in Japanese rather than having an English voiceover?

Tags: jiro-dreams-of-sushi

In [*Jiro dreams of Sushi*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1772925/) (2011), director David Gelb could have used an interpreter for the interviews to present the information in English. Instead, the whole documentary is in Japanese with English subtitles. Why do you think that the director took this approach?

Comment: Do you think it's an unusual choice to use subtitles rather than dubbing the voices?   I'm curious as to whether there is something I don't understand about this choice in this documentary in particular - its quite a common choice - many people like to hear a real person's voice rather than an actor.  Dubbing feels unnatural.

Comment: It's a documentary about a Japanese master of preparing a Japanese cuisine in a Japanese restaurant. Why should it be in English?

Answer (score 4):

As it's been pointed out in the comments, dubbing a documentary about a Japanese chef, in an all-Japanese setting, would seem a bit "off". Furthermore, it seems to matter even more for director David Gelb, as [his Twitter account](https://twitter.com/thisisdavidgelb) greets you with [the following pinned tweet](https://twitter.com/ThisIsDavidGelb/status/1046212428051050501):

> **@ThisIsDavidGelb** - Please turn on original audio and subtitle in the settings! The show is not meant to be dubbed.

[image: David Gelb Twitter account with the above text]

The tweet refers to his show [*Chef's Table*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4295140/), the episodes of which presents a variety of chefs from all around the world; hence, it is likely that Gelb thought of the same for his *Jiro Dreams of Sushi* movie. In [another tweet](https://twitter.com/ThisIsDavidGelb/status/990256074329677824), he explicitly stated he preferred the subtitles:

> **@ThisIsDavidGelb** - Thanks so much for watching Chef’s Table and for all of the feedback! For those who prefer subtitles to the dubbing, you can switch the audio to the original language and turn on subs in the @Netflix app. *(poll reads 86% subs, 14% dubs)*
>
> **@victormarkwhat** - Thank you! This is great to know. I just came across your twitter because we were watching Chefs Table S4:E2, did not like the dubbing. We were wondering if anybody else felt the same. Much better with subtitles!
>
> **@ThisIsDavidGelb** - Seems most prefer the subs, as do I.

[image: Gelb and his community prefer subs]

Answer (score 0):

Probably for the same reason some of us prefer to watch anime subtitled. There's a certain emotion and nuance in the tone that may not get properly conveyed with a dub.

Comment: And...as a non-Japanese you feel confident you actually get that nuance and tone in a language you understand *zero* of?